# In android studio, Gradle sync Build model taking too long

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to android development and just installed android studio. It's the first time I'm opening studio. Gradle: Build model is taking long time. It's been already 50mins and still continuing and no message in console. I don't know what to do. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Can you open your task manager and check network activity, if I'm not wrong something is downloading and essential for running a project? If so, don't worry, it will just download for the 1st time.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a cloud_firestore package? If so, it usually adds to the build compilation time significantly. But you should provide more details - if its android emulator or iOS and your code.
If its Firestore Cloud + iOS emulator

> Improve iOS Build Times# Currently the Firestore iOS SDK depends on
> some 500k lines of mostly C++ code which can take upwards of 5 minutes
> to build in XCode. To reduce build times significantly, you can use a
> pre-compiled version by adding 1 line to your ios/Podfile inside your
> Flutter project;
>
> pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git =>
> 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag
> => '8.6.0'
>
> Add this line inside your target 'Runner' do block in your Podfile,
> e.g.:

```
 # ... target 'Runner' do   pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag
 => '8.6.0'
 # ... end
```

Additionally, ensure that you have upgraded your cocoapods to 1.9.1 or higher: gem install cocoapods

> For more information see this issue:
> https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2751